# How to make Augment Reality using Pose data from Tango?

Tags: augmented-reality, google-project-tango

Augment reality doesn't work if Auto-Connect is disabled in Tango Manager and if auto-Connect is enabled it doesn't allow any ADF to load.
So how can we use pose data of an ADF to make AR objects that are persistent and appear with respect to the ADF origin?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use ADF files you'll have to connect manually like described here: https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-user-permissions

Auto-connect and Area Description Files can't work together for obvious reasons as auto-connect is done on startup and an ADF would first have to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses AR+ADF together, it is a good reference for you too:
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaLearning